# How do I add a simple form that includes two hidden elements in Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I know this question should be really simple, but for some reason thoroughly understanding Forms has alluded me over the years.

Basically, I want to create a new 'feedback' - which can be thought of as similar to a Tweet.

So when you are entering the text - which can only be done when you are logged in, (i.e. `current_user` is set), it should automatically store the `poster_id` and the `receiver_id`.

Here is my `Feedback` model:

```
class Feedback < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :poster, :class_name => 'User'
    belongs_to :receiver, :class_name => 'User'

end
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: feedbacks
#
#  id          :integer         not null, primary key
#  poster_id   :integer
#  receiver_id :integer
#  content     :string(255)
#  created_at  :datetime
#  updated_at  :datetime
```

This is my `_form` partial for the creation of new Feedback objects/records.

```
<%= form_for(@feedback) do |f| %>
  <% if @feedback.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@feedback.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this feedback from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @feedback.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  <div class="poster_id">
    <%= f.hidden_field(:poster, current_user) %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="receiver_id">
    <%= f.hidden_field(:receiver, @user) %><br />
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.text_field :content %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried this, but the error I keep getting is:

```
undefined method 'merge' for nil:NilClass
```

I am pretty sure I am not doing this right, but just based on the API docs and the guide, I can't quite figure out how to do it right and why.

So if you could tell me not only what the solution is, but also why that is the case, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks.

Comment: Hi - so are you saying that if you take out the hidden_field calls from the above, you dont get the error, ie the error is on rendering the form and not later, when submitting it?

Comment: you shouldn't set `poster_id` to `current_user` in your view, but do that in the `create`/`update` action in your controller. or do both. but without that, anybody could post a feedback as another user.

Comment: @ChrisKimpton yes that's exactly what I am saying. Once I take out the `hidden_field` tags, it doesn't throw that error. Naturally the form doesn't work because the `Feedback` model is looking for `poster_id` and `receiver_id` both of which can't be found without being explicitly included.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  <%= f.hidden_field "poster_id", :value => current_user.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field "receiver_id", :value => @user  %>
```

Actually, I am not really sure about @user. Maybe you want @user.id or something?